# client-side pagination with ngGrid

Tags: angularjs

Trying to do pagination on clientside.

my code:

```
angular.module('MainViewController', []).controller('DashboardController', function ($scope,$http, DashboardService) {

    $scope.jobsData = [];

DashboardService.getDashboardData().then(function (response) {
        if (!response) return;
        $scope.jobsData = response;        
    });


 $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page) {
        setTimeout(function () {           
                $scope.setPagingData($scope.jobsStatus, page, pageSize);       
        }, 100);
    };
```

Not sure how do we set getPagedDataAsync without Json return type